# kendo combo box filtering not working

Tags: kendo-ui, asp.net-mvc-5, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have implemented the kendo combo box control and trying the implement the filter option. The text field that I am displaying is concatenated field. I have 
set the following properties but the filtering doesnt seem to work. When the user types the first few charectors it should filter the records

```
.Filter("contains")
.ServerFiltering(true)
```

It doesnt work for my other combo boxes that doenst contain concatenated fields either. Am I missing somthing

```
 <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Company, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <div class="editor-field">
                            @(Html.Kendo().ComboBoxFor(model => model.CountryCode)
                            .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:100%" })
                            .DataTextField("CompanyCodeCompany")
                            .DataValueField("CountryCode")
                            .Filter("contains")
                            .MinLength(3)
                            .Events(e => e.DataBound("onCompanyComboChange"))
                            .Value(@user.DefaultCountryCode)
                            .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                            .Read(read => read.Action("RequestHeader_SalesOrganisation", "Request").Type(HttpVerbs.Post))
                            .ServerFiltering(true)
                            )
                            )
                        </div>
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Company, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
```

**Controller**

```
  public ActionResult RequestHeader_SalesOrganisation()
        {
            var response = requestRepository.GetSalesOrganisation().AsQueryable().ProjectTo<SalesOrganisationViewModel>();

            var jsonResult = Json(response, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            jsonResult.MaxJsonLength = int.MaxValue;
            return jsonResult;
        }
```

Comment: you have to implement it server side manually, or you can set  .ServerFiltering(false) to make it client side.

Comment: I set the .ServerFiltering(false) .it doesnt work.Do you have sample of how it is done manually

Comment: look  t this post http://www.telerik.com/forums/combobox-with-server-filtering-not-working, note filter parameter on read method.

Comment: Try using `.Filter(FilterType.Contains)` instead of `.Filter("contains")`

Comment: tried just putting Filter(FilterType.Contains) .No luck

Comment: Seems that filtering should be set on server side with action method parameter e.g. `string filter`: `var response = requestRepository.GetSalesOrganisation().AsQueryable().Where(x => x.PropertyToFilter.Contains(filter)).ProjectTo<SalesOrganisationViewModel>();`